# Why access rights in windows prevent run qt project

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gdb, access-rights

Some weird behavior occured after I had built my project with qt creator. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185843/why-gdb-not-loads-dlls), `gdb` didn't load `DLLs` when it resembles in folder `C:\svn\trunk\src\debug`. After I've changed rights via `cygwin` console with `chmod ugo+rwx` `DLLs` sarted to be able to load via `gdb`.

So I've moved project to my user's home folder (`C:\Users\Juriy\trunk`). But it seems like weak workaround. I want to understand why `Windows`, that had never had troubles with such a situations, when accessing files from `C:\` with admin user's rights, started to do so.

PS. Recently I used `mingw` and `qt 4.8.1` and was able to build project from `C:\svn\trunk\src` directory. I has the same environment, with `Cygwin` installed and has no problems.